# How to create GKE cluster using gcloud ruby client

Tags: ruby, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, gcloud-ruby

Am trying to create a GKE cluster using the [gcloud-ruby-container gem](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/main/google-cloud-container).

But there seems to be [close to 0 documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference/google-cloud-container/latest) on how to do this. Not sure if am not finding the correct docs.

1. I installed the gem and authenticated using service account json successfully
2. Figured out how to call the create_cluster gRPC method like below. Not sure about the parent parameter though.

```
location_path = Google::Cloud::Container::V1::CreateClusterRequest.new(project_id: "PROJECT_ID", parent: "REGION")
response = cluster_client.create_cluster(location_path, cluster_params)
```

I am unable to figure out the structure of the `cluster_params` object. The available options can be found in the [rest API docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters). But passing an object with these aattributes doesn't seem to work. Am getting an error like `unknown keywords: :name, :nodePool`, ... etc.

Any ideas on how to use this client library?